# Twilio API receive extra parameters I have passed to a call

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am using the Call Resource from Twilio API and I need to get the extra parameters I have passed to calls I have made. In my application I pass the extra params with query params such as `.../Calls.json?foo=bar`. These extra params hold information for the client and such. However when I try to get all the calls from Twilio API through `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC789cf80fc3910717722e21f7714c5b98/Calls.json` I get all the calls but there is no trace of these extra params passed to the call. I was able to get some of these params in the Notifications resource where it included the Request URI I made, but the Notifications resource did this only for error messages. What is the way to do something like this? Should I include status callbacks and check for each one manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These query parameters are sent to your application, which consumes them. This is how you would access them, not as you found, via the historic /Calls resources logs.

[How to Share Information Between Your Applications](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/how-share-information-between-your-applications)

[Passing Custom Information via Requests to Twilio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011213347-Passing-Custom-Information-via-Requests-to-Twilio)

Comment: Does this hold true for the digits that are gathered when a call is in process? Meaning, does my application have to actually save them in a database, because they are not saved by Twilio?

Comment: Yes that is correct. If you use Twilio Studio, is has its own logs where the `Gather Input on Call` widget information is captured. Studio REST API v2 Resources - https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/v2#studio-rest-api-v2-resources.